# 301 redirect partialy working. need help

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301

i'm using the standard redirection which works partialy.

it does redirect to the new page, but in the browser it keeps the old url as if it's still on my website. i would like instead to show the new url so the user will go next time directly to the new page and not the old one.

so, if i type in the old-url.php the server would redirect to new-url.php, but in the browser user can see the old-url.php. i would like the browser to show the new-url.php

should i use php to redirect the browser to the new url?

note, i'm not using any databases, so i can only do this through htaccess and php

i wouldn't like though to use php as the files from which i'm redirected are deleted from my server and creating them just for redirection, would make a mess on my website.

i'd like to stick to htaccess

Comment: What is "the standard redirection"? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type a full path in your .htaccess eg...

```
RewriteRule ^old/address http://www.example.com/new/address [R=301]
```

Based on your .htaccess..

```
RewriteRule ^old.php http://website.org/directory/new.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it will not redirect the browser to the new url. only the server

Comment: @user656931 Actually `R=301` will send the Location header to the browser. If this does not happen you probably have some conflicting rules. youcan try `[R=301,L]` but even that is not enough if your rules are not synhronzed.

Comment: here you can see entire htaccess code line http://www.mediafire.com/?otexu03raau4rmd

Comment: tried it yep, here you can see entire htaccess code lines mediafire.com/?otexu03raau4rmd

Comment: the http:// was there; removed the / from the old.php. browser still won't redirect. now just to make sure you understand what i need: if i type in the browser the old-url.php the server would redirect to new-url.php, but in the browser user can see the old-url.php. i would like the browser to show the new-url.php

Comment: maybe because the old-php file is deleted from the server might cause the issue ?

Comment: Put this line on top of other rewrite rules, right after RewriteBase, if needed add ^directory/old.php (I don't know file structure). Remove Redirect 301 rule. It will redirect because you have rule if file doesn't exists apply rules. Experiment :)

Comment: placing it under rewrite base and above the index.php redirection and without any ^ or / for the old url, did the trick. thank you for your help. so the final line is RewriteRule old.php http:// website.org/directory/new.php [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this in PHP?

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Comment: i would like to avoid the use of php.

Comment: Well, I suggested this because you mention you have control over php... *shrugs*

Comment: yep, it's ok .. ty though. your help is much appreciated